# How can I know if the data sent from the client side were manipulated or not before inserting it into the database?

Tags: php, android

**The android app:**

I'll send the device name and the model number to the server side when the user signs in.

**The server side (PHP):**

How can I know if the device name and the model number were manipulated or not before inserting it into the database?

**Why do I need to store the device name and the model number in the database?**

I want it to tell the owner of the account when someone is trying to sign in to his account and give him the device info who trying to sign in.

I think this is not possible to know if the device name and the model number were manipulated or not. But I hope I was wrong.

Comment: Whether on not manipulation is possible, or even easy, depends on your code. We can't see your code, so we can't help you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think the code is not needed, Everything is clear, Let's suppose your API link will receive an email, password, device name, and model number. You can verify the email and password if true or not from the database, But how can I know if the device name and model number are already not manipulated? Here is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're funny: "Everything is clear".  OK, let's do this without any code. What your Android app needs to do is create a hash of the data that it sends. Then when your API receives the data it can check that against the hash it receives. The trick here is to create a hash that a hacker cannot easily emulate, for instance by using a secret seed or "token". You can even change this token regularly, for instance every time the user signs in.